# creating a fuzzy search using mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm New to Mongo_DB and I'm Trying to create a fuzzy search.

the problem is that the object is not populated inside an aggregation so I cant access the data inside it.

this is an example from the model :

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("63d23f433730e5f8e12ccddd"),
    program_name: X,
    description: X,
    program_type: X,
    exercises: [x,x,y,y],
    d_t: X,
    author: 
      new ObjectId("63a8acd4828ee44cc4d21802"),
    program_for: {
      _id: new ObjectId("63b145c5e7d56927142dab1b"),
    }
  }
```

the search need to return a value via firstname/last from inside the **program_for** Object

I tried this query ,

```
const search_program = await Program.aggregate([
          { 
            '$search':  { 
              'index': 'searchPrograms',
              'text': {
                'query': `${search_field}`,
                'path': 'program_for.firstname',
                fuzzy: {"maxEdits": 1},
              },
              }
          }])
```

** search field is a variable which user enter the firstname / lastname to search

I hope I was clear enough..
Thank You For your help !

Comment: Remember to [.exec](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) the aggregation pipeline on the model

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I will be very thankful if you can explain a little more , i tried : await Program.aggregate([ { '$search': { 'index': 'searchPrograms', 'text': { 'query': ${search_field}, 'path': 'program_for.firstname', fuzzy: {"maxEdits": 1}, }, } } ]).exec()